# Conditionally styling @font-face

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using @font-face for some headers.

The replaced typeface is different in dimension and overall character. When the switch happens, the old typeface's rules don't look so good.

Other than writing a conditional Javascript script, is there a way to have a set of CSS rules for @font-face fonts (if the browsers supports it) and CSS rules for the unreplaced default fonts?

Comment: Six questions, 0 accepts? Pass.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about how things look before the page is finished loading?  Who cares.

Comment: There aren't any relevant browsers that don't support @font-face at this point.

Comment: @reisio: you obviously don't work in a bank, law firm, hospital, government agency, third-world country...

Comment: I don't work someplace that relies on irrelevant browsers, if that's what you mean, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no events that fire when this switch happens. So if you wanted to change line-height for instance, browsers don't give you any way to know when to do it.

However,

The [new Google WebFont Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html) provides CSS and javascript hooks so that you can change anything whenever that new @font-face font applies.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at typekit - they provide events in their javascript library that help you control load events.